# How to use mysql values as column names to reduce the number of rows?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT uo.id as visited_object, uo.id, uo.parent_object, object_username,
       object_title, object_type, lat, lng, uop.propertyName,
       uop.propertyContent,
       (SELECT avg(child_value) FROM `uf_object_childs` uoc
        LEFT JOIN uf_objects uo ON uoc.object_id=uo.id
        WHERE uoc.child_type='rev_rating') as object_rating
FROM `uf_objects` uo
LEFT JOIN uf_object_properties uop ON uo.id=uop.objectId
WHERE uo.object_type='page'
```

The query above returns the following

[image]

How can I change it so it returns only a single row on which propertyName values will be used as column names and propertyContent is used as their respective values.

Which means I get only one row with three extra columns named cover_photo, city and address on which their values are http://...., New York and Lincoln Square, New York ... respectively.

Any one can help me to figure this out ?

Comment: Is the number of potential values for `propertyName` limited and always known in advance? If so, this can be done as a straightforward pivot table. If not, and there are many potential values for `propertyName` and not all are known in advance, you need to use dynamic SQL to create it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for which properties you want to have columns, you can do it quite simply like this, assuming each property exists only one for each 'object'.

Basically, you group by the object id, and aggregate the property value. I'm using `max`, but you could use `min` just as well. It's just a way to aggregate the properties and pick one of the values. Which one it is, is determined by the property name using the `IF` function (you could use `CASE` as well).

```
SELECT 
  uo.id as visited_object, uo.id, uo.parent_object, object_username,
  object_title, object_type, lat, lng, uop.propertyName,
  uop.propertyContent,
       (SELECT avg(child_value) FROM `uf_object_childs` uoc
        LEFT JOIN uf_objects uo ON uoc.object_id=uo.id
        WHERE uoc.child_type='rev_rating') as object_rating
  MAX(IF(uop.propertyName = 'cover_photo', uop.PROPERYVALUE, null)) AS cover_photo,
  MAX(IF(uop.propertyName = 'city', uop.PROPERYVALUE, null)) AS city,
  MAX(IF(uop.propertyName = 'address', uop.PROPERYVALUE, null)) AS address
FROM `uf_objects` uo
LEFT JOIN uf_object_properties uop ON uo.id=uop.objectId
WHERE uo.object_type='page'
GROUP BY 
  uo.id
```

Note though, that the reason you have to do this with this, if I may say so, suboptimal query, is because your data model isn't very good either. The object data (id, user, parent, object_title, etc) is stored redundantly which is usually a bad sign.

Normally, you'd either make actual columns for properties like 'cover_photo', so you don't have to duplicate the object_title and those other fields.

Alternatively, you could create a separate table of object_properties that contains a label and a value per object. This is especially useful if you don't know what the properties will be, but if you do, the suggestion above is better. And for such a separate table, you would still need a query to 'pivot' the data into the flattened for you asked for, but at least the data itself wouldn't be stored redundantly.